# Unable to block error traces in a Symfony 3 controller

Tags: php, twig, symfony

I am studying the `Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug`. 
As far as I know the AppKernel's constructor can accept a second argument to define whether to use the debug modality or not (`true`/`false`).
What I actually don't understand is the usage and complementarity of `Debug::enable()` as it is indicated in the app_dev.php on the official Symfony Github's [repository](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/app_dev.php#L25).

For example I tried to throw an `Exception` on a Controller in order to see the effect and I commented `Debug::enable();` within app_dev.php but I always see the [error page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html).

Why am I still seeing error traces in spite of commenting out `Debug::enable();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short explanation**

The `Debug::enable()` method registers a fallback error handler, which will be called if your application failed to handle an error.

The error page you see when kernel is booted with the `$debug` flag set to `true`, is a result of your application error handling (implemented by an exception listener). Set the flag to `false` to disable stack traces. If you're only after testing you can also [disable error pages in development](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#testing-error-pages-during-development).

The page shown by the Debug component is not as nice as the one provided by the exception listener, but it's nicer than the PHP one.

**Detailed explanation**

The front controller calls your application kernel:

```php
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$response = $kernel->handle(Request::createFromGlobals());
```

The application kernel boots itself, creates the container and calls the http kernel to handle the request:

```php
public function handle(Request $request, $type = HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = true)
{
    if (false === $this->booted) {
        $this->boot();
    }

    return $this->getHttpKernel()->handle($request, $type, $catch);
}
```

The http kernel will use the event dispatcher to trigger certain events (`kernel.request`, `kernel.response`, `kernel.exception` etc). When an exception is thrown while handling the request, the http kernel will catch it and trigger the `kernel.exception` event:

```php
// the following code is simplified to show the point

public function handle(Request $request, $type = HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = true)
{
    try {
        return $this->handleRaw($request, $type);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $this->handleException($e, $request, $type);
    }
}

private function handleException(\Exception $e, $request, $type)
{
    $event = new GetResponseForExceptionEvent($this, $request, $type, $e);
    $this->dispatcher->dispatch(KernelEvents::EXCEPTION, $event);

    // ...
}
```

One of the listeners registered by default in the Symfony Standard Edition is the `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener`. It's responsible for rendering nice error pages.

However, it will only handle exceptions thrown while handling a request in the http kernel. So if anything goes wrong outside of this call, it won't be handled (have a look at the catch blog in the previous code example).

This is where the Debug component comes in. The `Debug::enable()` method registers an error handler, an exception handler and a special class loader. You can use it in any PHP project without the http kernel. It is sort of a fallback error handler which will be called if your application failed to handle an error. It has no relation to the `$debug` constructor argument in the kernel.